# how to control/modify the activity textview from viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2

[image]
I have a viewpager which has five tab  and control the tab with tablayout. the problem that i have is that the title doesn't change when want to go from one activity to another activity. the thing that i do is that i changed the textview title in tablayout in onTabSelected in the activity but in both on select tab and in on reselect tab method but sometimes it doesn't change anymore.
another thing that makes the point is  the map which i use the address of the map in my main activity title. i changed the address using setOnCameraChangeListener method and the problem with this case is that it run several time even when i am in another fragment and because i used it's address in my main activity title it change it.

at he also changed the title in both onViewCreate and onCreateView in each fragment but it doesn't work fine.

this is what everything that i did:

```
public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public Context context;
    public Typeface tf;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public static boolean a=false;
    private CustomViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_montakhab,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_search,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_issue,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_profile
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
         tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "IRANSans_Bold.ttf");
        context=this;

        TextView google_header_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.google_header_address);

        tabCustomization();

        setupTabIcons();

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#f6fda6"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
        ImageView firstTab=(ImageView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
        firstTab.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#f6fda6"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


        google_header_address.setText("");


        google_header_address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }


    private void tabCustomization() {
        viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new MenuFragment(), "tab1");

        adapter.addFragment(new AddressFragment(), "tab2");
        adapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment(), "tab3");
        adapter.addFragment(new IssueFragment(), "tab4");
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(), "tab5");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);


            tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(tabLayout,i));

        }


        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        Log.i("TabChild",String.valueOf(tabsCount));


// Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view

    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){


            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                TabChanges(tab);

            }

            private void TabChanges(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                linearLayout=(LinearLayout)tab.getCustomView();
                ImageView v=(ImageView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
                v.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#f6fda6"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                TextView google_header_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.google_header_address);


                switch (tab.getPosition())
                {
                    case 0:
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));


                        google_header_address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        google_header_address.setText("");

                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_bw_small)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                    google_header_address.setText("tab2 title");

                        ClearFragmentStack();



                        Log.i("bwSmall", "title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab3 title ");

                        Toast.makeText(context,"title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab4 title");

                        Log.i("bwSmall", "title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)));

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab5 title");

                        Log.i("bwSmall", "title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)));
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                 linearLayout=(LinearLayout)tab.getCustomView();
                ImageView v=(ImageView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
                v.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                TextView google_header_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.google_header_address);
                google_header_address.setText("");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                linearLayout=(LinearLayout)tab.getCustomView();
                ImageView v=(ImageView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
                v.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#f6fda6"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                TextView google_header_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.google_header_address);

                switch (tab.getPosition())
                {

                    case 0:
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));

                        google_header_address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        google_header_address.setText("");

                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_bw_small)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab2 title");

                        ClearFragmentStack();



                        Log.i("bwSmall", "title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab3 title");

                        Toast.makeText(context,"title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab4 title");

                        Log.i("bwSmall", "title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)));

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ClearFragmentStack();
                        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
                        google_header_address.setText("tab5 title");

                        Log.i("bwSmall", "title"+String.valueOf((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mtext_size_button)));
                        break;

                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void ClearFragmentStack() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
        public View getCustomView(TabLayout tabLayout,int position){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabLayout, false);
            TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

            textView.setText(getPageTitle(position));
            textView.setTypeface(tf);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(tabIcons[position]);

            return view;
        }
        public View getTabView(TabLayout tabLayout,int position) {
            // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabLayout, false);
            TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

            textView.setText(getPageTitle(position));
            textView.setTypeface(tf);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(tabIcons[position]);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }

    //Caligraphy Library
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

and this is what everything that i do in the first tab which have product address that i use it in my title and also show the current location on the map.

```
public class _step1_mapfragment extends Fragment {


    MapView mMapView;

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    public static boolean Stop_searcLocation=true;

    public LatLng GetCurrentLocation;

    public ImageView IV_title;
    public ImageView IV_marker;

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_ID = 234;
    private String FilePath;
    public String FIleName = "images.jpg";

    ImageView Prescription_img;

    // directory name to store captured images and videos


    public _step1_mapfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    Uri file;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__step1_mapfragment, container, false);
        Change_MarkerImage(rootView);
        Control_Map(savedInstanceState,rootView);

        GeocodeAsyncTask AddressTask=new GeocodeAsyncTask(UIHelper.Latitude,
                UIHelper.Logitude);
        AddressTask.execute();


        FilePath=getActivity().getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/files/";
        try {
            copyfile(getActivity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File f = new File(FilePath + FIleName);
        Log.d("FileName:",f.getName());
        Prescription_img= (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.prescription);

        ClearFragmentStack();
        fav_GetAddress(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void ClearFragmentStack() {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }

    private void Change_MarkerImage(final View rootView) {
        IV_marker = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_address_map_custom_marker);
        IV_title = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Image_title);
        IV_marker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IV_marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_new_mark_icon);

                IV_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        IV_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked well",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               /* checksCameraPermission(view);*/
                IV_title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                TakeImage();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == -1) {

                Bundle args=new Bundle();

                // I'll assume this is a Context and bitmap is a Bitmap

                File fileUrl=new File(file.getPath());
                args.putString("image",fileUrl.getAbsolutePath());
                _step2_fragmentconfirm_pic confirmPicFragment=new _step2_fragmentconfirm_pic();
                confirmPicFragment.setArguments(args);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"getting image ready",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.root_menu_fragment,confirmPicFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack("mapView");
                transaction.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Everything is ok but frag error is the case", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }


    public void copyfile(Context context) throws IOException {

        Log.d("File Path:",FilePath);
        InputStream myInput=context.getAssets().open(FIleName);

        String outFileName=FilePath+FIleName;
        OutputStream myOutPut=new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            myOutPut.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        myOutPut.flush();
        myOutPut.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    private void TakeImage() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {


            file = Uri.fromFile(ImagePicker.getTempFile(getActivity()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                TakeImage();
            }
        }

    }






    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Stop_searcLocation=true;
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();

        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    private void Control_Map(Bundle savedInstanceState, View rootView) {
        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {


                googleMap = mMap;
                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                    }
                });
                googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

                        UIHelper.Latitude=cameraPosition.target.latitude;
                        UIHelper.Logitude=cameraPosition.target.longitude;

                        GeocodeAsyncTask AddressTask=new GeocodeAsyncTask(cameraPosition.target.latitude,
                                cameraPosition.target.longitude);
                        AddressTask.execute();


                    }
                });

                // For showing a move to my location button
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    },1);
                }

                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map

                googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                       {
                            Stop_searcLocation=false;
                            GetCurrentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Set Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(GetCurrentLocation).zoom(18).build();
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                        }

                    }


                });


            }
        });
    }





    class GeocodeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Address> {
        double strLatitude;
        double strLongitude;
        public GeocodeAsyncTask(double strLatitude, double strLongitude){
            this.strLatitude=strLatitude;
            this.strLongitude=strLongitude;
        }
        String errorMessage = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        @Override
        protected Address doInBackground(Void ... none) {
            Log.i("Started","start one");
            Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fa"));
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            double latitude = strLatitude;
            double longitude = strLongitude;

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                errorMessage = "Service Not Available";

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                errorMessage = "Invalid Latitude or Longitude Used";

            }


            if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Log.i("Started", "start two");
                return addresses.get(0);

            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Address address) {
            Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fa"));
            Log.i("Started","start three");
            if(address == null) {

            }
            else {
                Log.i("Started","start four");
                String addressName = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    if(i==0)
                        addressName +=  address.getAddressLine(i);
                    else
                        addressName += "،" + address.getAddressLine(i);
                }
                Log.i("Started", String.valueOf(address.getMaxAddressLineIndex()));
            Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fa"));
                UIHelper.setTvText(getActivity(), R.id.google_header_address, addressName);
            }
        }
    }

    public  void fav_GetAddress(View view){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_custom);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.draw_radius_cost_info);
        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button


        TextView dialogButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        LinearLayout imageView=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.fav_GetAddress);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
// custom dialog

    }
```

Comment: You can do it by holding an `instance` of the currently added fragment where you are initializing `viewpager`.

Comment: An easy solution would be to use an `EventBus` . Let me know, if you need I ll add an implementation as an answer!

Comment: @OBX would u please to give me an implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach would be to use an `EventBus` . Which allows publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another (and thus be aware of each other). It is designed exclusively to replace traditional Java in-process event distribution using explicit registration. In order to use `EventBus` in Android, inside your gradle(app level) add:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Now you'll need to create an `Event` . An event is just an object that is posted from the sender on the bus and will be delivered to any receiver class subscribing to the same event type. That's it!. So for this purpose we'll create a sample `Event` class:

```
    public class HelloWorldEvent {
    private final String message;

    public HelloWorldEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Now the next step is to create a `Sender` . Which allows you to post any event from any part of your whole Android application. So in your case you can send from Fragments, viewpager,etc . This is how you do it:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new HelloWorldEvent("Hello EventBus!”);
```

So this sends a new `event`, however in order to receive this, you'll need someone to receive it. So in order to listen from any activity, say from your activity class, at first you'll need to register it:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

Then inside that class define a new method :

```
// This method will be called when a HelloWorldEvent is posted
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(HelloWorldEvent event){
  // your implementation
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So, what happens is whenever an `Event` is sent, it will be received by the `receiver` . So You can create one `Event` and add multiple listeners to it. And it will work fine, as shown in the below image:

[image]

More info on the `EventBus` library is available here:

- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

A simpler tutorial on `EventBus` is available here:

- [How to use the greenrobot EventBus library](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/)

Comment: In case of any doubt, do ask in the comment