# Passing a data from Dialog to Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tags

I'm currently working in my own project of dental application, i would like to ask if how to pass a certain data from a custom dialog and show or add it to the target fragment?

Appreciate for any help.

This is the Custom Dialog Screenshot:

[image]

CustomDialog.java

```
package com.bloxofcode.multipletabs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import com.bloxofcode.multipletabs.Tab1;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public CustomDialog d;
    public Button yes, no;

    ToggleButton btnGenderMale,btnGenderFemale;
    Button btnCancel, btnAccept;
    EditText eText;

    public CustomDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.drawable.dialog_holo_light_frame);
        }
        else{
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);


        btnGenderFemale = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonFemale);
        btnGenderMale = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonMale);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnAccept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
        eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        btnGenderMale.setChecked(true);

        btnGenderMale.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonMale, boolean b) {
//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                                String.valueOf(buttonMale.isChecked()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(buttonMale.isChecked()){
                    btnGenderMale.setEnabled(false);
                    btnGenderFemale.setEnabled(true);
                    btnGenderFemale.setChecked(false);
                }else{

                }
            }
        });

        btnGenderFemale.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonFemale, boolean b) {
//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                                String.valueOf(buttonFemale.isChecked()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(buttonFemale.isChecked()){
                    btnGenderMale.setEnabled(true);
                    btnGenderFemale.setEnabled(false);
                    btnGenderMale.setChecked(false);
                }else{

                }
            }
        });


        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Sample",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

How to achieve this Expected Result:

[image]

Tab1.java

```
package com.bloxofcode.multipletabs;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.bloxofcode.multipletabs.database.DBOpenHelper;
import com.bloxofcode.multipletabs.database.NotesProvider;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    private ImageButton imgButton;
    private CustomDialog customDialog;
    View v;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        imgButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        //Creating ImageButton

        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello Image Button!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                customDialog = new CustomDialog(getActivity());
                customDialog.show();
            }
        });

        press();
        return v;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public void press() {
        insertNote("Juan Dela Cruz");

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                DBOpenHelper.ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null);
        String[] from = {DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};
        CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,from,to,0);

        ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }

    private void insertNote(String noteText) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT,noteText);
        Uri noteUri =getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,values);

        Log.d("MainActivity","Inserted note " + noteUri.getLastPathSegment());
    }


}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.bloxofcode.multipletabs;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else if(position == 1)
        {
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }
        else             // As we are having 3 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        }


    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

TabsActivity.java

```
package com.bloxofcode.multipletabs;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Patient","Appointment","Backup"};
    int Numboftabs =3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);


        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                //return ContextCompat.getColor(TabsActivity.this,R.color.tabsScrollColor);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor,TabsActivity.this.getTheme());
                }else {
                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
                }
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful ?

Comment: hi sir i used interface...and haven't try yet the eventbus...but will try it...thanks

Comment: Ok, Interface is an option as well. Do mark my answer if it was least helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it using `Interface`.

**YourInterface.java**

```
public interface YourInterface{
    void yourMethod(int data);
}
```

Use that Interface in your Dialog class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements
    View.OnClickListener {

    private YourInterface delegate;

    ....

    public CustomDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
        delegate = (YourInterface) a;
    }

}
```

In your Activity that holds fragment implement interface:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourInterface {

    ....

    @Override
    public void yourMethod(int data) {
        fragment.receiverMethod(data);
    }

}
```

**Tab1.java**

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    public void receiverMethod(int data) {
        // do what you want with received data
    }
}
```

Now to use that simply call `delegate.yourMethod(data)` to pass it to fragment

Comment: Hi Sir I'm a little confused about using the interface, do i need to include the onAttach method for this?

Comment: Hello! Yes you need to override `onAttach` method, because it is the easiest (if not the only) way to get the context/activity that can be casted to your interface.

Comment: Hi Sir im kinda newbie here, connecting all the codes. But im using a viewpageadapter in the code i tried to create an interface and implements it to my TabsActivity but i always getting an error.

Comment: @iamcoder What errors do you get and which part of answer is not clear to you?

Comment: i think this link helps me to understand a little bit on interface..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279787/how-can-i-pass-values-between-a-dialog-and-an-activity

Comment: Hi sir currently my TabsViewActivity is implementing ViewPagerAdapter class that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter i will edit my post to paste the code for the ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134745/discussion-between-marat-and-iamcoder).

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to keep things loosely coupled and structured, A fine rather alternative is to choose the `EventBus` . To see the usage see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952654/4738175).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast Receiver in your onDismiss like below in your Dialog

```
@Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (onDismissListener != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("DialogDismiss");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            onDismissListener.onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }
```

and in your Fragment you can receive the broadcast

// In your Fragment do below

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //Work Here
        }
    };
```

//In OnCreate

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("DialogDismiss"));
```

//onDestroy

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the view from the `customDialog` you can just access the fields normally with `view.findViewById()` from in your fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data into budle as key-value pair and set bundle as an argument to fragment. 
fragment.setArgument(bundle)

To get bundle in fragmen, call
Bundle bundle = getArgument() and get values from the bundle based on key.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the String which was entered into the EditText by creating a setter and getter method within your Dialog class to return a String variable (e.g. `editTextString`) which you would assign a value to whenever the accept button is clicked.

Add your getter and setter methods to the Dialog class

```
private void setEditTextString() {
  editTextString = eText.getText().toString()
}

public String getEditTextString() {
  return editTextString;
}
```

Within your click listener for the accept button add the following line of code:

`setEditTextString(eText.getText().toString());`

Then all you need to do to return the value entered in the editText field in the Fragment class would be to call the public method within your Dialog class to return the string.

`dialogClass.getEditTextValue()`

Comment: In your setEditTextString() function, you made it with no parameter. But inside your accept button, you used it and passed eText.getText().toString() which is incorrect.

Also by doing this, assuming that that the fragment got the passed value, it will return null since in Fragment it's getting the data already even if there is no click event yet