# Sending data from Broadcast Reciever to Fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to update a variable's value in my fragment every 24 hours using a broadcast receiver and cannot understand how to update the variable data even after a lot of research.

This is the function I am using for the calling the alarm every 24 hours and send the variable which needs to be incremented to the Alarm Receiver both of which are working fine.

```
    public void scheduleAlarm() {

    Intent intentAlarm= new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReciever.class);
    intentAlarm.putExtra("imageName",""+imagename); // variable to be updated
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

}
```

After doing some research I haven't been able to understand how to transfer to value retrieved and incremented to be sent back to the Fragment. This is my reciever class.

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("servicerun","true");
    String intentImageName = intent.getStringExtra("imageName");
    int numberImageName = Integer.parseInt(intentImageName) +1; // How to send this value back to the fragment?
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this link http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/04/example-of-using-alarmmanager-to.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more structured way would be to keep these classes loosely coupled and link them together using an `EventBus`. Which seamlessly allows you to pass data as event to multiple classes. To see the usage, check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952254/how-to-control-modify-the-activity-textview-from-viewpager-fragment/41952654#41952654)

Comment: How would the data be sent back in the onEvent function when the data has been recieved and now needs to be sent back  @OBX

Comment: Data sending from where and receiving from where?

Comment: when the data is sent from the fragment  using the post method of event busand then afterwards retrieved from the onEvent method in the Reciever class using 'event.getmessage()'. i need to update that message and send it back to the fragment.  @OBX

Comment: You can create multiple events as well as multiple subscribers for a single event. In your case, you can send an event from fragment to broadcast receiver, and receive it in broadcast receiver, and when you receive that in broadcast receiver, you can make another event from broadcast receiver, and set the subscriber for that as a fragment. So you'll get the update back

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer but i am facing another problem. when the app is destroyed and restarted the previously initialized data is used. How can I fix this.? @OBX

Comment: Post another question, with all strictly relevant data, someone will help , pass a link as well, if I can I'll :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42066715/6273398 Hey, if you help me on this that would be wonderful @OBX