# Communicating between fragment and parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a fragment with a list view on it, and the user is able to select items in that list. Whenever at least one item is in a selected state I would like to reveal a "delete" toolbar button on the *parent activity*. Would I just raise an event from the fragment to achieve this?

What about doing the deletion - should the activity or the fragment be responsible for this? Either way the activity would need to somehow ask the fragment to either do the deletion, or ask it to reload the list (if the activity does the deletion).

Really looking for best practices for this kind of activity/fragment communication, and to reduce the coupling (presumably interfaces will play a part too).

For a second (related) question, my fragment is currently responsible for retrieving the list's items from the database, but in a book I've read they show the activity doing this instead, which then passes the items to the fragment. What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to all of your sub questions, keeping the classes loosely coupled and linking them using an `EventBus` is the ideal way to go for!

`EventBus` allows publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another (and thus be aware of each other). It is designed exclusively to replace traditional Java in-process event distribution using explicit registration.

This seamlessly allows you to pass data as event to multiple classes and listen to those events from multiple other classes as well.  To see the usage, see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952654/4738175)