# Android : button in toolbar onclick prompt message in another two tablayout

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-tablayout

i have a question, is it possible to make it , when onclick the button in toolbar and prompt the message in another two tablayout fragment. For example, when i click the button test in my bottom toolbar, another two fragment textview will prompt up with text.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
int ans =3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    BasePagerAdapter adapter = new BasePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
    Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();


    adapter.addFragment(tab1, "1");
    adapter.addFragment(tab2, "2");


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
public class BasePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public BasePagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }


    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Tab1

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {



EditText editext,editext2,editext3;
Button test;
DBController db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    editext =(EditText)h.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editext2 =(EditText)h.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editext3 =(EditText)h.findViewById(R.id.editText3);



    return  h;
}
```

Tab2

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
TextView textView2;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
    textView2 = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have a question, is it possible to make it , when onclick the button in toolbar and prompt the message in another two tablayout fragment

Answer : **YES**

How so ?

well, using `interface` is a solution. But I would rather keep the classes loosely coupled and use an `EventBus`, Which seamlessly allows you to pass data as event to other classes.

It follows a publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another (and thus be aware of each other). It is designed exclusively to replace traditional Java in-process event distribution using explicit registration.

To see the usage, see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952654/4738175)

Comment: thanks, is there any simple tutorial about the event bus?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, this is the easiest I ve found so far : http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/

Comment: As it's a bit outdated, you'd need to compile the latest version

Comment: Also you'd need to add @Subscribe annotation from now on to listen to events, which is also shown in the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41952654/4738175

Comment: Mark the answer as complete, if it was helpful!

Comment: i applied event bus in my tablayout, but there is a problem , the eventbus only passing data for 3 tablayout others can't receive, is it the evnt bus gt any limitation in tablayout?